# Truffle Test: How to test SafeMath Library for overflow

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, unittesting, truffle-test

How can I test if a function is resistant against overflow with truffle test?

```
contract SafeMath{    
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract TestSafeMath{ 
    function test_add_10_and_max_should_return_err() {
          uint256 max = 2**256 - 1;
          uint256 expected = "revert overflow error";
          Assert.errorsEqual(SafeMathExt.add(10, max), expected, "Addition of 10 and max should revert");
    }
}
```

`TestSafeMath
    1) test_add_max_and_10_should_return_err
    No events were emitted
    1 failing`

How can I get this test passing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't know how your code can compile, this is obviously an issue

```
uint256 expected = "revert overflow error";
```

and also the *errorsEqual* method of the assert library [is expecting two error codes](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/solidity-tests/lib/testing/Assert.sol#L1346)

Anyway one way of going around this would be trying to make a raw call in order to test if there's a revert status inside the VM. The call method will return true in case the call has been executed correctly, false otherwise.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/SafeMath.sol";

contract TestSafeMath {
  SafeMath instance;

  constructor() public {
    instance = SafeMath(DeployedAddresses.SafeMath());
  }

  function testAdd_10_and_max_should_return_err() public {
    uint256 max = 2**256 - 1;
    bool passed = address(instance).call(bytes4(keccak256("add(uint256,uint256)")), 10, max);

    Assert.isFalse(passed, "test should fail");
  }
  function testAdd_10_and_10_should_be_ok() public {
    uint256 value = 10;
    bool passed = address(instance).call(bytes4(keccak256("add(uint256,uint256)")), 10, value);

    Assert.isTrue(passed, "test should not fail");
    Assert.equal(instance.add(10, value), value + 10, "should be 20");
  }
}
```

To get the actual value you need to invoke again the method since the raw call won't give you the return value (see the second test method).

output

```
  TestSafeMath
    ✓ testAdd_10_and_max_should_return_err (53ms)
    ✓ testAdd_10_and_10_should_be_ok (66ms)


  2 passing (987ms)
```